# displaying views from ASP.NET MVC project from a winforms project

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, winforms

I have this idea where I would like to generate some forms in html and then display them in winforms in a web browser control.
The hitch is that I am not sure how to go about doing so.

Is it possible to have one solution with an ASP.NET MVC project and a Windows forms (or WPF) project and call display the views from the asp.net project in a web browser control in the windows forms project?

I am trying to put together a quick test project and have done the easy stuff so far:

- I have a class library containing the DAL for handling DB access
- I have an MVC project with a controller and a view which generates some data for testing
- I have a windows forms project with a form and a web browser control.
- I have realised that I haven't got the faintest clue as to how to go about to navigate to the view from my MVC project.

If somebody could explain to me how to go about displaying the MVC view in the winforms browser I'd be most grateful.

EDIT:

Basically what would like to figure out how to do is this:

In the form containing my web browser, I'd do something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DisplayReport();
    }

    public void DisplayReport()
    {
        this.webBrowser1.Navigate(MyMvcProject.Controller.MyCoolView);
    }
}
```

And I'd get the html from MyCoolView displayed in the web browser control... I just don't have a clue how to do it, what using statements are required etc.

Comment: You'd need a view engine as well (to actually convert all of the view's parts into a document) which means you'd need a lot of manual tinkering since this normally done in a web context.

Comment: I can see now that as you say it is not a realistic option. It would be an interesting exercise, but a waste of time from a productivity point of view I guess. If you put this down as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This link shows how you can communicate between the web browser control and your wpf/winforms app. This works seamlessly and is a very neat way to facilitate two way communication between the browser control and the web page 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Sep/27/Calling-JavaScript-functions-in-the-Web-Browser-Control

It requires a scripting object that you define as a regular class. Methods defined on this object can be called from the Website in JavaScript through the `window.external.WhateverMethod`

EX:

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("test",
            new String[] { "called from client code" });
```

This calls the JavaScript method "test" - defined on the webpage (and passes a string variable.)

Comment: This is not quite what I want to do. I would like to know how to load a view from my MVC project in my Winforms project, but this is about how to interact with the web browser control. Or am I misunderstanding what you are trying to tell me?

Comment: You can command the MVC project from your winforms project using this approach. It will enable you to run java script defined in your pages to control your web app

Comment: yes, that's what I thought, but that would suppose that I already have something loaded in the web browser, which I don't... I would like to know how to load the page in the first place.

Comment: Ok, Can you define a proxy page that just facilitates the loading of the actual page you want to display using JavaScript? Load the proxy page initially and command it through the web browser control

Comment: Ah, that's not a bad idea. I'll look into it.

Comment: That didn't work either, because again I do not know how I can load the views from the other project. I think that would need a custom view engine as @bzml said above.

Comment: perhaps the proxy page can load the real page as an ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be possible but you would have to create a bunch of object yourself. In a sense, it might be similar to unit testing where mocks are created for many objects.

In the past, I have used that function (from Inside a controller function) to create a string by rendering a partial view and it was used to generated emails from an ASP.NET MVC application.

```
    protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        ViewData.Model = model;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = 
                ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);

            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, 
                viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);

            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```